# IPython/Jupyter notebook shortcut not working on Mac

Tags: macos, ipython, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-notebook

I had a hard time figuring the keyboard shortcut.

Is that true that I should press `Ctrl-m` together and press the other key such as `d` to delete one cell? I tried it but it did not work for me I also tried without `-` but it still does not work for me :(

I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to first toggle the right cell state.

The newer version of IPython revamped the command structure, so that cells have two states: input mode, when the cell has a green outline, and command mode, when the cell has a grey outline.

When its green you can edit the content and run it. When its grey you can use the delete insert cell or copy commands.

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd> activates the green state, while using <kbd>Esc</kbd> activates the grey state.

For example:

To delete a cell, use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go in command mode, like the grey outlined cell below, and simply press the <kbd>d</kbd> key twice.

[image: img]

Comment: great!! It works!! so it means that I don't have to use `ctrl-m` any more, just use `esc` right? Another question is besides delete, do you know any other short-cuts need double click? I can't find the description online...@agconti

Comment: yep! you dont need control-m anymore.  what do you mean by double click?

Comment: I mean to press `d` twice...sorry for the imprecision...are there any other shortcuts which need to be pressed twice as well?

Comment: @MYjx I'm not to sure myself, but for the full list of available shortcuts, click Help, Keyboard Shortcuts in the notebook menus.

Comment: Here are my 2 cents. In jupyter version 4, when Esc is pressed, the cell now turns blue and not grey. The small edit symbol disappears from the right top corner of the notebook.

Answer (score 5):

On my mac, I use <kbd>fn</kbd> key, instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, to make shortcuts work in iPython notebook (in Safari). For example,

- <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> deletes a cell (<kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> works too)
- <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> cuts a cell
- <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> copies a cell
- <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> undoes an action,

and so on. As already noted above, you must press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before applying any of these shortcuts; that is, you first hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to make a cell "grey", then you press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> to cut a cell.

Answer (score 2):

You first press `Ctrl` and `m` (don't press the minus key), that will put the interface in command mode. For deletion you then have to press `d` twice.

Comment: it still did not work for me no matter how many times I hit the `d` :(